# CSS3 Animation getting stucked until hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a CSS3 animation to "blink" an img on my site.

My .dot its just a black dot in the page, and i want it to blink (opacity from 1 to 0 and backwards)

The secuence would be this:
- Load page --> Animation start running
- Hover the .dot --> Animation pauses
- Hover out --> Animation start running again

It works...but sometimes when i load my web, they are in pause mode. And when i hover them, they activate and start running.
I'm using chrome.

Some idea??

My code:

```
.dot {
position: absolute;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
background-color: black;
border: 4px solid white;
border-radius: 99999px;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-animation-name: example;
-o-animation-name: example;
-webkit-animation-name: example;
animation-name: example;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-o-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.dot:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: animation 1s 16 ease;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation: animation 1s 16 ease;
    -o-animation: animation 1s 16 ease;
    animation: animation 1s 16 ease;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* The animation code */
@-moz-keyframes example {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes example {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nachogarrone/33j2Lzq6/3/

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Nikki added the jsfiddle, its not working fine yet, i assume im forgetting to import something!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me... what browser are you using?

Comment: Now, the fiddle its working fine :)

Comment: @MikeB. I'm using Chrome

Comment: Got a question what do you want it to do ? Like every time you hover the dot it will run the animation and when you leave you want it to... ?

Comment: @Nikki I want to animate alwasys by default, unless i hover it and it should pause and start again when i take the mouse out. The problem is, sometimes when i load the page it isn't running!

Comment: If you want to you can try this as far as I know it works every time when you load the page https://jsfiddle.net/33j2Lzq6/7/

Comment: @Nikki comment it like a solution so i can mark it. I try it a few times and it works ok! Seems like we should force it sometimes to start working...Thanks!

Comment: I added a post would you mind mark it as the answer

Comment: @Nikki you will need to take the time to write up an answer here, explaining your solution. Please do so—you're making the web better!

Comment: Yeah I'll think of that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nikki i could get to one solution.

With JS, i could call this function when the DOM completely loaded, this way i force the css to start.

```
var listdot = document.getElementByClassName("dot");
function Start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < listdot.length; i++) {
        listdot[i].style.WebkitAnimation = "example";
    }
}
```